# Create an index in mongodb with more than one field using java

Tags: java, mongodb, indexing, mongodb-indexes

I am new to `MongoDB`. By default, collections in `mongodb` have index on `_id` field.I need to create an index on 2 more fields using Java.

```
DBObject indexOptions = new BasicDBObject();
indexOptions.put(field_1, 1);
indexOptions.put(field_2, -1);
collection.createIndex(indexOptions )
```

When i query that in mongodb using db.collection_name.getIndexes()

```
[
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "_id_",
                "ns" : "schema.collection_name"
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "field_1" : 1,
                        "field_2" : -1
                },
                "name" : "field_1_1_field_2_-1",
                "ns" : "schema.collection_name"
        }
]
```

I am not sure if the above is correct.
Can someone please confirm? If not correct,how can i correct it ?

Adding to the above, for retrieval i am doing something like this:

```
        DBObject subscriberIdObj = new BasicDBObject( field3, value3 );
        DBObject subscriberIdIsNullObj = new BasicDBObject( field3, null );
        BasicDBList firstOrValues = new BasicDBList();
        firstOrValues.add( subscriberIdObj );
        firstOrValues.add( subscriberIdIsNullObj );
        DBObject firstOr = new BasicDBObject( "$or", firstOrValues );

        DBObject batchIdObj = new BasicDBObject( field1, value1 );
        DBObject fileNameObj = new BasicDBObject( field2, value2 );
        BasicDBList secondOrValues = new BasicDBList();
        secondOrValues.add( batchIdObj );
        secondOrValues.add( fileNameObj );
        DBObject secondOr = new BasicDBObject( "$or", secondOrValues );
        BasicDBList andValues = new BasicDBList();
        andValues.add( firstOr );
        andValues.add( secondOr );

        DBObject query = new BasicDBObject( "$and", andValues );
        DBCursor cursor = mongoDatastore.getDB().getCollection(collection_name).find(query);
```

Now, for fast retrieval like above should i create index separately on field1,field2 and field3? or compound index on all the 3 fields?

Comment: Yes. What you have done is correct. You have created a composite Index with the two fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is correct and is called `Compound Index`. You have created an index on two fields: `field_1` (ascending) and `field_2` (descending). So for example if you will sort by `field_1` ascending and `field_2` descending or by `field_1` descending and `field_2` ascending, MongoDb will use this index `field_1_1_field_2_-1` for it.

However, the above index cannot support sorting by ascending `field_1` values and then by ascending `field_2` values. Also if you search or sort only on `field_2`, it will not use this index. In this case you can create a separate indexes for `field_1` and `field_2`.

To check if your query is using index, try to use `explain()` and see which cursor is used. For example, you can try such query:

```
db.your_collection.find({ "field_1" : "something" }).explain()
```

If you will see that the cursor which is used is `BtreeCursor`, then the query uses the index, in case of `BasicCursor` it does not.

For more information, just refer to [this article](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-compound/).

Comment: Thanks Yuriy..i may want to search only for field_2 so do i need to create a separate index for that? Do you mean to say this index will only work when i search for field_1 and field_2 combined(as a whole)?

Comment: Yes, if you need to search only for field_2, then you need a separate index for it, but don't forget that writes will be slower. This index will work for field_1 and field_2 combined, but not in all cases as I described above and also it should work if you search by field_1 only.

Comment: I read that indexes slow down inserts..so considering both write and read operations will occur on equal proportions, should we go for indexes or not?

Comment: That's right, all depends and your db structure and queries you make :) A lot of factors depend on this. At least you can see what are you doing more: if reads - then you definitely need an index, and if writes - you need to think if you need them or not.

Comment: If you find this answer useful, please accept it as the best answer.

Comment: I will accept..Just one last query which I have updated in my question..can you please answer it?

Comment: It is hard to say in terms of SQL, but I think that compound index of all 3 should work. However, I'm not sure, and would definitely check my mongo query with the explain() command to see if index is used as I described above.

Comment: I have updated my post with the actual mongodb retrieval using Java for which i want to create indexes

Comment: As I already said, check it in the command line using explain(). I don't think that your compound index will be used here. For this case I would create some other index.